# WPF New window close listener

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataGrid` on my main window and some clickable views which open a new window. I want to "refresh" the `DataGrid` when the new window closes.

Comment: solution will depend on how have you implemented your code for closing the  window. is it code behind or vm or ?

Answer (score 1):

Attach to Closing Event of the new windows. In you MainWindow you should have something like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var secondWindow = new SecondWindow();
    secondWindow.Closing += (s, args) => this.Refresh();
    secondWindow.Show();
}
```

however, in some situation its is viable to show blocking modal dialog. In that case:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var secondWindow= new SecondWindow();
    secondWindow.ShowDialog(); //this will wait until window is closed
    this.Refresh();
}
```